# How to print multiple variables in multiple strings in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, printing

I am trying to use values from dataframe into a print function but I just can't get it to work.

```
    digits  counts
0   43  174
1   27  166
2   34  164
3   1   163
4   17  162
5   13  161
6   4   161
7   12  160
8   33  159
9   39  158
10  10  157
```

So, that's my dataframe and I want to create something like this.

```
The number {43} appeared {174} times. 
The number {27} appeared {166} times.
```

Comment: Can't get _what_ to work? What have you tried?

Comment: Try this: `for x,y in df.iterrows(): print(f'The number {y["digits"]} appeared {y["counts"]} times')`